# How to deallocate container with pointers C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Suppose I have a container of type C with pointers of type T*.

```
C<T*> c;
```

How can I properly deallocate this container without using auxiliary
functions like

```
template<class C>
void delete_all(C& c) {
    typename C::iterator next(c.begin()), last(c.end());
    while (next != last) {
        delete(*next);
        ++next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. (Let's fill this up.)

Comment: You can write your own container and do the de-allocation in the destructor (or use one of the boost containers that do that for you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using C++11, you could use `C<std::unique_ptr<T>> c` instead. Pre-C++11 you could try `C<std::auto_ptr<T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to specialize the C template then put your code in destructor of specialization for pointers.

```
template<> class C<T*> {
   //...

   C<T*>::~C () {
      // clean up
   }
}
```

But then you need to worry about lifetime of your containters a bit.

If you meant STL containers then you can't do this but you can use some smart pointer type instead of raw ptr - like boost::scoped_ptr or std::unique_ptr in C++11.

Also Boost Pointer Containers might help:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html